# How to et to data-thumb

Tags: jquery, url

I have an img which looks like this:

```
<img data-thumb="//i4.ytimg.com/vi/G9S_E2NgSM8/mqdefault.jpg" src="http:///yts/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif" alt="Miniatuur" width="182">
```

I want to do something with the url resided in data-thumb. If it was `img src` I would have used `prop` or `attr`, I tried this for data-thumb but it doesn't work. How do get to the url in data-thumb with Jquery? (couldn't find anything on internet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('img').data('thumb');
```

See http://api.jquery.com/data/ for more.

Comment: I put a var like this `qwerty = $(data).find('img').data('thumb');` When I use it I get 'undefined' in console, but maybe Im writing it wrong. anyway I think this is as good as it gets:) Thank you.

Comment: `$(data).find` won't work since it doesn't mean anything. You need to select an actual element.

Comment: Im doing Ajax call with screen scraping php, this is what the 'data' stands for. Its basically a complete website.